# Semgrep determine value of function parameter

Tags: semgrep

I have this Semgrep rule to detect:

any usage of:

`new $X.Classic(..., {..., classicName: $Y, ...})`

where: classicName's value matches with this regex: `.*hello.*`

```
rules:
  - id: tyq
    languages:
      - ts
    message: Hello
    pattern-either:
      - patterns:
          - pattern-either:
              - pattern-inside: |
                  import * as $X from '@abc/abc';
                  ...
          - pattern-either:
              - patterns:
                  - pattern: |
                      new $X.Classic(..., {..., classicName: $Y, ...})
                  - focus-metavariable: $Y
                  - metavariable-comparison:
                      metavariable: $Y
                      comparison: re.match(".*hello.*", $Y)
```

and this works if $Y is:

1. hardcoded string: (classicName: "hello")
2. a variable assignment within scope

ex:

```
   #1 var varName = "hello";

   #2 new $X.Classic(..., {..., classicName: varName, ...})

or if #2 is within some function and #1 is in root of file
```

but DOES-NOT work if:

the value of classicName is coming from a function parameter.

like:

```
class Class {
  constructor() {
    super();
    const classicName = "hello";
    this.createClassic(classicName);
  }

  private createClassic(classicName: string) {
    new abc.Classic(this, 'MyBucket', {
      //ruleid: tyq
      classicName: classicName,
    });
  }
}
```

Any way I can catch the values of parameters of function. (As in this case parameter value is resolvable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to track data across functions, you likely want to leverage [taint mode](https://semgrep.dev/docs/writing-rules/data-flow/taint-mode/).
Taint mode functions by determining if any data from a "source" reaches a "sink". The idea would be to mark any string matching you regex as a source, and then any instance of the usage you want to detect as a sink. The rule below implements this.

```yaml
rules:
  - id: tyq
    languages:
      - ts
    message: Hello
    mode: taint
    pattern-sources:
      - patterns:
          - pattern: $X
          - metavariable-regex:
              metavariable: $X
              regex: .*hello.*
    pattern-sinks:
      - patterns:
          - pattern-inside: |
              import * as $X from '@abc/abc';
              ...
          - pattern: "new $X.Classic(..., {..., classicName: $Y, ...})"
          - focus-metavariable: $Y
    severity: WARNING
```

[Playground](https://semgrep.dev/playground/s/pKGEN)

The `focus-metavariable` in the sink restricts it such that the source has to reach that specific point, rather than just anywhere in the sink pattern. If we didn't have that, we'd also match instances where our source reached say, the first parameter. I've also swapped out the `metavariable-comparison` for `metavariable-regex` as a stylistic choice. Note also that `$X` in the sources and `$X` in the sinks are independent. If you wanted to write a rule where they had to be the same thing (as they would if they were combined under a `patterns`) you could use the `unify_taint_mvars` option, but that isn't needed here.

One downside to this rule: it is overbroad, since if anything marked as a source is used to compute the value `$Y` matches, the rule with match. You could use [sanitizers](https://semgrep.dev/docs/writing-rules/data-flow/taint-mode/#sanitizers) or [tweak some other options](https://semgrep.dev/docs/writing-rules/data-flow/taint-mode/#minimizing-false-positives) to cut down on the noise.

Here's [an example](https://semgrep.dev/playground/s/3qxLW) with an additional finding which I assume is an FP (depends on if you want to forbid this, or if you only care about the final value which reaches the object).

There are some limitations to taint analysis in the OSS version, so you'll have to use the [pro engine](https://semgrep.dev/docs/semgrep-code/semgrep-pro-engine-intro/) if you want interprocedural or interfile analysis.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the rule, it works. wdym by ` since if anything marked as a source is used to compute the value $Y matches, the rule with match` can you provide a couple of example?
Thanks!

Comment: I've added an example of what I mean: https://semgrep.dev/playground/s/3qxLW (`y` itself won't necessarily satisfy your regex since `bar` might change it arbitrarily). However, if you mostly just expect static strings to end up in the constructed object then this is likely a non-issue.

Comment: Ohk, got it, this ideally won't be an issue.

Assuming the bar() function is present in context, is there a way with public-Semgrep, it's (output of bar()) value can be determined and for the above playground to work?

Comment: it works, ignore the question. https://semgrep.dev/playground/s/eqL18

Thanks!

Comment: Hey @kopecs,
this flags the issue even if function is not called and it just uses the name of the variable for matching, any workaround?

https://semgrep.dev/playground/s/OrO2B

Comment: You can restrict the source to just be a string literal: https://semgrep.dev/playground/s/9AWEY

Comment: Hey, this seems not to be working for cases where string template is used like:
`xyz-${region}-xyz` https://semgrep.dev/playground/s/ReOz8

Answer (score 1):

Try and modify your [Semgrep rule](https://semgrep.dev/docs/writing-rules/rule-syntax/) to trace variable values when they are passed as arguments in function calls. That will require adding a new pattern to handle function parameter tracing.

I tried:

```yaml
rules:
  - id: tyq
    languages:
      - ts
    message: Hello
    pattern-either:
      - patterns:
          - pattern-inside: |
              import * as $X from '@abc/abc';
              ...
          - pattern-either:
              - patterns:
                  - pattern: |
                      new $X.Classic(..., {..., classicName: $Y, ...})
                  - focus-metavariable: $Y
                  - metavariable-comparison:
                      metavariable: $Y
                      comparison: re.match(".*hello.*", $Y)
      - patterns:
          - pattern-inside: |
              class $CLASS {
                ...
                private $METHOD($PARAM: string) {
                  ...
                }
                ...
              }
          - pattern: |
              new $X.Classic(..., {..., classicName: $PARAM, ...})
          - focus-metavariable: $PARAM
          - metavariable-comparison:
              metavariable: $PARAM
              comparison: re.match(".*hello.*", $PARAM)
```

You now have an added pattern block, which targets cases where `classicName` is a parameter of a method within a class.
It searches for the `new abc.Classic` call inside a method where `classicName` is passed as an argument.
The [`focus-metavariable`](https://semgrep.dev/docs/writing-rules/experiments/multiple-focus-metavariables/) and [`metavariable-comparison`](https://semgrep.dev/docs/writing-rules/data-flow/constant-propagation/#metavariable-comparison) are used to focus on the parameter and apply the regex comparison.

But, it does not seem to work.
Semgrep operates primarily by pattern matching on the code's syntax tree, rather than executing or deeply analyzing the runtime behavior of the code. That means that while it is excellent for detecting certain types of code patterns or antipatterns, it has limitations in tracing the flow of variable values, especially when they are dynamically determined, such as being passed through function parameters.

Given this limitation, that Semgrep rule may not be able to trace the value of `classicName` when it is passed as a parameter through multiple function calls, especially if the value is set in a different scope or is dynamically generated.

A potential solution, although not foolproof, is to look for direct assignments or initialization of the parameter within the same function scope. However, this will not catch cases where the value is set elsewhere or passed down through multiple layers of function calls.

For the specific case you mentioned, where the value of `classicName` is coming from a function parameter, a possible workaround is to broaden the scope of your pattern to catch any instance of `classicName` being passed as a parameter, and then manually review these instances. That approach increases the likelihood of false positives, but can be useful in scenarios where thoroughness is more critical than precision.

[Playground](https://semgrep.dev/playground/s/v8ZB4)

```yaml
rules:
  - id: tyq
    languages:
      - ts
    message: Hello
    pattern-either:
      - patterns:
          - pattern-inside: |
              import * as $X from '@abc/abc';
              ...
          - pattern-either:
              - patterns:
                  - pattern: |
                      new $X.Classic(..., {..., classicName: $Y, ...})
                  - focus-metavariable: $Y
                  - metavariable-comparison:
                      metavariable: $Y
                      comparison: re.match(".*hello.*", $Y)
      - patterns:
          - pattern-inside: |
              class $CLASS {
                ...
              }
          - pattern: |
              new $X.Classic(..., {..., classicName: $PARAM, ...})
    severity: WARNING
```

Comment: Hey, it's not working for me in Playground: https://semgrep.dev/playground/s/eqrwl

Comment: @NikhilVerma True. I have edited the answer to propose a workaround. Not really satisfactory, but still, it might help.

Comment: Hey, this seems to be flagging for any value of `classicName`. I kind of see what you mean, but earlier it was not working when i added pattern to match two different scope and match variable b/w them.

Comment: @NikhilVerma I agree. That is why I mentioned it as a workaround.